# How can I change app language in app delegate?

Tags: ios, swift, localization

I am working on an ios app which currently supports two languages English and Korean. I want to add a condition in the app delegate that If the phone language is supported by the app then the app will open in that language otherwise it will open in the english language. I have tried the following code in app delegate, but it is not working. Can anyone helps me in this.

```
if UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "lang") == nil {
     let langCodeString = Locale.current.languageCode
     let preferredLanguage = String(Locale.preferredLanguages[0].prefix(2))

     if let languageCode = langCodeString {
            if languageCode == "ko" && preferredLanguage == "ko" {
                UserDefaults.standard.set(["ko"], forKey: "AppleLanguages")
                UserDefaults.standard.set("korean", forKey: "lang")
                UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
            } else {
                UserDefaults.standard.set(["en"], forKey: "AppleLanguages")
                UserDefaults.standard.set("english", forKey: "lang")
                UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
            }
      }
 }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Simply set English as the base localisation for your app. Then if the phone locale isn't supported by your app, English will be used.

Comment: Yes, the base locale of the app is English. But let us suppose I have changed my iPhone language to Korean, installed the app & it is working in korean language, which is right. But then I deleted the app from my phone and changed the phone language to Hindi. Then the app is supposed to work in english but for the first time it runs in korean language and when I quit the app and run it again then it is running in english. But I want that it runs in the english from the first time I installed it again. This is the issue I am facing.

Comment: After I switched the app to the Hindi language and installed the app, I am getting korean language code from the Locale. That's why I am facing the issue. But I don't know why It is returning korean language code instead of hindi. When I have already selected Hindi as the phone language.

Answer (score 0):

Just try to save the preferred language in KeyChain.
Please refer a [link](https://github.com/soffes/SAMKeychain).

However, if you prefer API for it and a backend to store translation, that will be a better solution though it will take sometime to load initially.